# Trying to make a timer function in MATLAB which can be called upon

Tags: matlab, timer

I am tring to make a function in MATLAB that can take in different arguments like a timer. Something like

```
function timercommand(arg)    
if arg == go    
for t = 1:100    
    pause (1)    
    if arg == stop    
    ...
```

Something like that. But I want to be able to call it like: `timercommand(go)`
and later call `timercommand(stop)`. But I really don't know how to do it.

I need the function to be able to Count down towards 0. If it reaches zero it should set itself to 'Stopped' and I have to be able to recognize that it has done that.

I also need to be able to stop the countdown myself to prevent it from activating other functions that I want to use together with this function.

As an example off what I am trying to (just an example off use) do is that I want to issue a reboot on my computer. I need the reboot to happen in a certain time if I do not respond or have enough time to halt it.

Hope that makes my question more understandable. Sorry for any confusion!

Comment: There are different possible approaches and it depends on what you want to achieve in the end. A problem in your proposed code is, that if the function is once started with `timercommand('go')`, execution is blocked by the for-loop and you'll not exit the function until the timer is done. So you cannot stop it by calling `timercommand('stop')`. It depends of *your application* and for this reason we can't give you a good answer to the current question. I'd recommend you to edit the question to include some more context information.

Comment: Also you should take care with string handling in matlab.
`if arg == go`
certainly does not do what you want it to do. Try
`if arg == 'go'`
or
`if strcmp(arg,'go')`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use a [**`timer`**](http://ch.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/timer-class.html)-object. It already does exactly what you want. Here is an example to start the timer with `start(T)` and stop the timer with `stop(T)`. The *`stop`-command* is commented out to test the behaviour. Before we can start the timer, we have to set some parameters like `StartDelay` for the time to wait (here 5 seconds) and the `TimerFcn` that gets called once the timer is done.

```
function TimerMain
    T = timer;                          % Create a timer object
    set(T,'StartDelay',5);              % Specify the time to wait
    set(T,'TimerFcn',@TimerCallback);   % Assign a callback-function

    start(T);                           % Start the timer

    %stop(T);                            % Stop the timer
    %delete(T);                          % Delete the object if no longer needed
end      

function TimerCallback(~,~)             % Gets called when timer is done
    disp('Reboot in progress!');
end
```

Note that instead of using the `set`-commands you can directly assign them when you call `timer` like this: `T = timer('StartDelay',5,'TimerFcn',@TimerCallback);`

Comment: Thank you so much! This was really helpful. Say I want to stop the timer. How do I do that? Do I have to manually remove the comment and then run it again or?

Comment: Just use `stop(T)` in the line you want to stop the timer. I commented it out so you can test what happens if the timer reaches 5 seconds. If you uncomment `stop(T)`, the callback-function never gets executed because you stop it before the timer is done.

Comment: Hi again matt! Can you check out my new lines of codes below? I'd really appreciate the help :)

Answer (score 0):

I would do something like this (the definition of t, the timer, is outside the main function so if you copy and paste it in matlab it won't work, but you should define consequently with the rest of your program):

```
t = timer('TimerFcn', 'stat=false; disp(''Timer!'')',... 
                 'StartDelay',1);

function timercommand(arg)
switch arg
    case 'go'
        start(t)
    case 'stop'
        stop(t)
end
```

I hope this helps!

Comment: This is exactly what I want. How do I make it count? And is it possible to make like an if statement to it? Like if I want to stop the timer at a certain time?

Comment: It does exactly that... you can stop it whenever you want. I will edit so it counts..

Comment: Yes I understand that, I am sorry I wasnt to clear about my problem. Is it possible to make it Count down and then stop?

I want to be able to stop it when it is running or when it has timed out it will set itself as 'Stopped'

Comment: Ok, let me check that ;)

Answer (score 0):

When you call your function `timercommand(arg)` you're out of the main function and while your `timercommand` is running your main would be at the same point. Event if you use command `arg == stop` your code will work only after the `timercommand(arg)`. 
The answer depends of your wanted result. 
For example for measure time between two clicks on button you can use event handlers (http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_external/using-events.html#responsive_offcanvas).
If you describe your problem with more details maybe somebody will help you. 
Good luck!